# How To Update Existing DynamoDB Table's Provisioned Throughput using AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to update my table's "read" throughput and keep "write" throughput the same.  The API requires you to set both the "read" and "write" values in the request but when one is left the same it throws an exception:

> Message: Error executing "UpdateTable" on
> "https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client
> error: `POST https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a
> `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"The provisioned throughput for the index regionCode (truncated...)
> ValidationException (client): The provisioned throughput for the index
> regionCode-index will not change. The requested value equals the
> current value. Current ReadCapacityUnits provisioned for index
> regionCode-index: 10. Requested ReadCapacityUnits: 10. Current
> WriteCapacityUnits provisioned for index regionCode-index: 2.
> Requested WriteCapacityUnits: 2. Refer to the Amazon DynamoDB
> Developer Guide for current limits and how to request higher limits. -
> {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"
> The provisioned throughput for the index regionCode-index will not
> change. The requested value equals the current value. Current
> ReadCapacityUnits provisioned for index regionCode-index: 10.
> Requested ReadCapacityUnits: 10. Current WriteCapacityUnits
> provisioned for index regionCode-index: 2. Requested
> WriteCapacityUnits: 2. Refer to the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide
> for current limits and how to request higher limits."}`

Here's the request:

```
$result = $client->updateTable([
    'ProvisionedThroughput' => [
    'ReadCapacityUnits' => (int) $readCapacity, // REQUIRED
    'WriteCapacityUnits' => (int) $writeCapacity, // REQUIRED
 ],
'TableName' => $table, // REQUIRED
```

]);

How do you update only 1 provisioned throughput capacity & leave the other the same?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that your table is provisioned to `2 - WCU` and `10 - RCU`, and you are trying to call `updateTable` with the same values as the currently set.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to do. I need to keep 1 value the same as existing and change the other.

Comment: I think it may be a design flaw in the SDK.

Comment: correct  you can increase provisioned throughput as often as needed, however, you can decrease it `no more than four times per table in a single UTC calendar day`, therefore SDK is doing a good thing and trying to prevent you from wasting number of times you can update throughput

Comment: but forcing me to increase throughput unnecessarily essentially using more of their resources for no reason.

Comment: The feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I think you are actually sending BOTH same values

Comment: Nope. Just one is the same.

Comment: I'm over 99.9% sure the exception only occurs if both values are unchanged